# Maximum Column Width based on Character Count

Tags: wpf, telerik, radgridview

I have a WPF application in which there is a Telerik RadGrid with 5 columns. My requirement is that the column width of each of these columns should be set based on the number of characters displayed in the column. For example, how can I set the column width, such that only 50 characters are displayed? (That is, how do I set the column width based on the character count?)

Answer (score 0):

Set the column width to `Auto`, and it will automatically size your width to the size of your content

Be sure your `RadGrid.Width` is not set to Stretch, or you have at least 1 `*` width column, otherwise it will stretch everything to fit the available space, instead of basing it's size off the content.